# How to deal with EmptyResultDataAccessException when using JdbcTemplate to retrieve data from database?

Tags: spring-mvc

I am getting below exception when I am going to retrieve data which does not exist in database. I am working with spring and using JdbcTemplate to do this. I want to get null in this situation. Can anybody give me a solution for this problem?

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.requiredSingleResult(DataAccessUtils.java:71)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:806)
at com.hojat.LibSpringMVCProject.DAO.BookDAO.getBookById(BookDAO.java:24)
at com.hojat.LibSpringMVCProject.service.BookService.getBookById(BookService.java:24)
at com.hojat.LibSpringMVCProject.service.TestService.main(TestService.java:37)
```

Comment: @Ivaylo has the right idea. Catch the exception and then just return null.
However, I honestly think throwing an exception is the most stupid way of signaling that there was no data returned from the database, the reason being that no data found is not at all an exceptional situation. I can check if the returned result set is null or empty to see if there was no data, I don't need an expensive exception telling me this.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return null from this query You should try catching the exception like this example:

```
    //Assuming your querying for varchar column
    String sqlSelect = "SELECT QUERIED_COLUMN 
    FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE YOUR_CONDITION = ?";
    try {
        return getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sqlSelect, 
        new Object[] {yourParam}, String.class);
    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider I want to retrieve the record from data base with id something, in my database id is 101 so i want to retrieve 101 details, when I run the program, o/p will generate like as follows

```
cid:101
cname:abhi
caddr:hyd
```

if you trying to retrive the data from the database and the data which is not exist in database then following exception will generate

Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0

there may be hardly 2 reasons to occur this exception,first one wrong data accessing and second one  the data which is not exist in the data base but you are trying to accessing, that's it.